# Como puedo traer todos los datos de SQLite a mi programa en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

tengo una tabla en SQLite que me almacena todos los datos de mi programa de parqueadero.

Como ven en la imagen a la derecha hay 4 columnas que muestran datos en el programa, lo que quiero hacer es que muestre todas las columnas almacenadas en SQLite en mi programa, pero solo logro mostrar las 2 primeras columnas de la base de datos. Agradeceria mucho su ayuda :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sospecho que la fecha y hora no las muestra porque el elemento tabla de tkinter no sabe cómo convertirlas. Probablemente de la base de datos te vienen en formato `datetime` o similar y la tabla espera que sean una cadena. Deberás convertirlas en cadena. Lo más simple puede ser usar `str()` alrededor de los valores de esas columnas, pero si quieres un formato más específico deberás investigar la función `strftime()`

Comment: @abulafia en realidad, está pasandole a la tabla solo los dos primeros valores de la fila. values espera un iterable (por ejemplo, una lista) donde cada item corresponde a la columna en esa posición (sin contar la creada por default). No habrá querido decir row[1:]?